# Do X.509 Certificate Serial Numbers Change When A Cert Is Renewed?

Tags: x.509

Do X.509 certificate serial numbers change when a certificate is renewed?

I understand the thumbprint changes, but I am unsure about the serial number. I suspect so since it's a new cert, but if you can provide clarity and links to documentation, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do.  A renewed certificate is just a new certificate.  RFC 5280 states this:

> The serial number MUST be a positive integer assigned by the CA to each certificate.  It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a given CA (i.e., the issuer name and serial number identify a unique certificate).

In addition, the CA/Browser Forum Baseline requirements state this:

> CAs SHALL generate non‐sequential Certificate serial numbers greater than zero (0)containing at least 64 bits of output from a CSPRNG.

This latter provision, which is stronger, was intended as a stopgap to prevent collision attacks when SHA-1 was still being used, but remains now even though SHA-1 is no longer being used. Issuing a certificate that does not meet these requirements is misissuance and can result in the CA being distrusted.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of serial number + issuer of a X.509 certificate is unique. This is needed for identifying certificates for revoking purposes etc. If you generate a certificate with a different validity periods its a new certificate and therefore its assigned a new and for that issuer unique certificate number.

See rfc5280

> The serial number MUST be a positive integer assigned by the CA to
> each certificate.  It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a
> given CA (i.e., the issuer name and serial number identify a unique
> certificate).  CAs MUST force the serialNumber to be a non-negative
> integer.